# Loss decreasing but predictions are empty

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, torchvision, unet-neural-network

I am currently implementing a UNet3D mo  del for a Brain Tumor Segmentation task using the BraTS2018 dataset but for some reason when training, the loss decreases but the predictions are all classified as background making all the metrics have a 0 score. The model I am using is the UNet3D from this repo: [Unet3D](https://github.com/HiLab-git/SSL4MIS/blob/master/code/networks/unet_3D.py).
Here is the code I am using for the training of the network:

```
    def train(args, logging_path):
      base_lr = args.base_lr
      num_channels = args.num_channels
      num_classes = args.num_classes
      batch_size = args.batch_size
      max_iterations = args.max_iterations

    def create_model():
        #return Swin(in_channel=num_channels, num_classes=num_classes, window_size=(4,4,4)).cuda()
        return UNet3D(in_channels=num_channels, n_classes=num_classes).cuda()
    model = create_model()
    ModelParamInit(model)

    def worker_init_fn(worker_id): 
        random.seed(args.seed + worker_id)

    labeled_train_loader = BraTS2018(base_dir=args.data_path,
                   split='train',num=None, img_type='all_modalities', transform=transforms.Compose([RandomRotFlip(), RandomCrop(args.patch_size), ToTensor() ]))

    trainloader_labeled = DataLoader(labeled_train_loader,
                                     batch_size=args.batch_size, num_workers=4,
                                     pin_memory=True, worker_init_fn=worker_init_fn)
    
    
    model.train()

    adam_optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=base_lr, weight_decay=0.0001)
    ce_loss = CrossEntropyLoss()

    logging.info("{} iterations per epoch".format(len(trainloader_labeled)))
    iter_num = 0
    max_epoch = max_iterations // len(trainloader_labeled) + 1
    best_performance1 = 0.0
    iterator = tqdm(range(max_epoch), ncols=70)

    for epoch_num in iterator:
        for i_batch, sampled_batch in enumerate(trainloader_labeled):

            volume_batch, label_batch = sampled_batch['image'], sampled_batch['label'] 
            volume_batch, label_batch = volume_batch.cuda(), label_batch.cuda()
            
            output = model(volume_batch)
            loss = ce_loss(output, label_batch.long())


            adam_optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            adam_optimizer.step()

            iter_num = iter_num + 1

            lr_ = base_lr * (1.0 - iter_num / max_iterations) ** 0.9

            for param_group in adam_optimizer.param_groups:
                param_group['lr'] = lr_

            logging.info('iteration %d : model loss : %f' % (iter_num, loss.item()))
            
            if iter_num > 0 and iter_num % 500 == 0:
                model.eval()
                metric_list = 0.0

                metric_list = test_all_case(model, args.data_path, img_type="all_modalities", num_classes=num_classes, patch_size=args.patch_size, stride_xy=64, stride_z=64)

                logging.info(
                        'Core: Dice Coefficient: %f Hausdorff Distance: %f' % (metric_list[0,0], metric_list[0,1]))
                logging.info(
                        'Edema: Dice Coefficient: %f Hausdorff Distance: %f' % (metric_list[1,0], metric_list[1,1]))
                logging.info(
                        'Enhancing: Dice Coefficient: %f Hausdorff Distance: %f' % (metric_list[2,0], metric_list[2,1]))

                model.train()


            if iter_num % 1000 == 0:
                save_mode_path = os.path.join(
                    logging_path, 'iter_' + str(iter_num) + '.pth')
                torch.save(model.state_dict(), save_mode_path)
                logging.info("save model to {}".format(save_mode_path))

            if iter_num >= max_iterations:
                break
        if iter_num >= max_iterations:
            iterator.close()
            break
    return "Training Finished!"

if __name__ == "__main__":

    cudnn.benchmark = True
    cudnn.deterministic = False

    random.seed(args.seed)
    np.random.seed(args.seed)
    torch.manual_seed(args.seed)
    torch.cuda.manual_seed(args.seed)

    logging_path ="./Logs/Iterations"
    
    print(f"args.exp: {args.exp}, args.model: {args.model}, snapshot_path: {logging_path}")

    logging.basicConfig(filename="./Logs/log.txt", level=logging.INFO,
                        format='[%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d] %(message)s', datefmt='%H:%M:%S')
    logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
    logging.info(str(args))
    train(args, logging_path)
```

Am I missing something very basic?
Thanks in advance